# Login Credential Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to ask about login credential. For example i have android application, how to make credential when user login after that when user close application an open again they unnecessary login again so application automatically redirect to home screen?

Thank you

(sorry my english is bad :D)

Comment: Fetch the token and save it in any persistent data store

https://flutter.io/cookbook/persistence/key-value/

Here are the docs. I have not used them myself so I cannot give an answer

Comment: Oke i got that, but when im redirect to home screen im getting error like "The following assertion was thrown building Builder: setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.". Im using Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed("/home");

Comment: Post more code. The bug is probably not that line.

Comment: this is my code : 

    override
    checklogin() {
      var items = storage.getItem('logincred');
      print("Login Cred : $items");
      if (items != null) {
        Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed("/home");   
      }
    }

    override
    void initState() {
      checklogin();
      super.initState();
    }

Comment: Way to call Navigator.push in InitiState() - https://stackoverflow.com/a/53041906/10269042

Comment: OMG Thx @anmol.majhail , It works!!!!